# How to animate a circle to move vertically using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to animate an object on button click. How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for *animate* function and set *top* style to something. Don't forget to set *position* to *absolute*.

Edit

```
<script>
  $("#clickaroo").click(
    function() {
      $("#movaroo").animate(
        { top: "+=100px", width:"100%" }, 1000);
    }
  );
</script>
<button id="clickaroo"></button>
<img id="movaroo" src="../Images/circle.gif />
```

Something like the above, perhaps? Needs some adaptation, of course, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Yes I can. Kindly, see my edit. If it's satisfactory, check it as answer and vote up. Otherwise, tell us why not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a circle object with arc function and add click event to the button object.

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
     $("#circleId").animate({top: "-=30px",width:"100%"},2500,"slow");
});
```